# PhalconPHP - camel cased model fields?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phalcon, camelcasing

I have a field in my database "user": "first_name"

When I create my Model User.php, I tried the following getter:

```
private $firstName;

public function getFirstName() {
   return $this->firstName;
}
```

This is NULL, while this one is filled with the correct values.

```
private $first_name;

public function getFirstName() {
   return $this->first_name;
}
```

Is it correct to use underscored variables here, and not camelCased ones?

Is there a possibility to use camelCased vars?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of what you want, not what you're afraid is proper or not. I personally like "underscore" table columns and camelCased PHP scripts.

Check [this one](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/127/phalcon-mvc-model-columnmap#C527) for how to declare `Model::columnMap()` in your model to have both functioning: underscored table columns, but camel-cased php vars.